# How to use a tab navigator inside a tab navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am new to React-Native and trying to create a app in which i want to use 2 tab navigator ; outer tab and inner tab.

outer tab for tanks, alerts and settings...
inner tab inside tanks for mapview and listview...

```
export default class Home extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    header:null
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <MyApp/>
    );
}
}
export const MyApp = TabNavigator({

tanks: {
screen: TanksScreen
},
alerts: {
screen: AlertScreen
},
 Settings: {
    screen: SettingScreen
 },
},
```

And this following code in TanksScreen

```
export default class TanksScreen extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
header:null
};

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  }
}
render() {
  return (
      <MapsView/>
  );
}
}
export const MapsView = TabNavigator({

Map: {
 screen: MapsScreen,
},
List: {
 screen: ListScreen,
},
},
```

By using the above code, i am able to get full functionality of outer tab navigator but when it comes to inner tab, the tab is neither not navigating to listview screen nor rendering any text or ui components in mapsview.

Am i doing anything wrong? or is there any way to accomplish this requirement. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since your `TanksScreen` component only returns the inner tabs, you can just plug them into the outer tab directly, which should solve the problem.

```
export const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  tanks: {
    screen: MapsView
  },
  alerts: {
    screen: AlertScreen
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingScreen
  },
}
```

Comment: using lazyLoad helped me with my problem. Anyways your answer also provided a simple way to use mapsView. Thank you @nimarod